# Image not shown inside Hero after navigating to ListView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

The original image is not shown inside a Hero widget after navigating to a screen with a ListView and scrolling to the bottom of the list and then navigating back

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyYhV.jpg)

I have already tried modifying my widget tree in different ways, but I have the impression that the problem lies in the fact that the first cells get deleted when we scroll down in the ListView and that the reference should be handled by the Flutter SDK.

Full code to reproduce can be found here -> https://github.com/hadleycode/flutter_hero_bug

Comment: I probably wouldn't label this as a bug or a problem with flutter as you do have options within the hero widget such as the flightShuttleBuilder to build the widgets that are inflight. Working with that builder may give you what you're looking for.

Comment: @AdrianMurray I have tried working with the flightShuttleBuilder (see this commit (https://github.com/hadleycode/flutter_hero_bug/commit/e1c54b51877904d2f0750aaaae52075d40210139) for more info), but this does not change the faulty behaviour in any way. There is still no image shown at all. The documentation for flightShuttleBuilder also says "If none is provided, the destination route's Hero child is shown in-flight by default"... Which is not the case in my example.

I have tried adding a placeHolderBuilder which half-resolves the problem, but it now kills intent of the original animation

Comment: Still, I'm not sure this is faulty behavior as the widgets that do not build are off the screen and the point of a Hero is to transition elements from one screen to another, meaning that items that aren't built are placed into the overlay as is. Something you could try is adding an initial animation to bring the elements you want together onto the screen prior to pushing the next page. Or you could maybe place the widgets in the list in a floating sliverpersistentheader and pass that to the next page. Keeping things built.

Comment: I think maybe the gif loop I posted is confusing as at the end it returns to the start where all the images are there... I completely agree that there should not be an animation when the widgets are off screen. However the original images on the first page are not displayed *at all* which is not defined behaviour according to the official documentation.

Comment: You mean that they don't even build *after* the transition is complete? That would most definitely be a bug. I wonder, if for now, you could try doing a setState after you pop back to the first page by using push().then((_){ setState((){});  })

Comment: Yes correct, the images do not build (as seen in the first part of the gif I posted). For a temporary solution I have kept the items in my list alive - which is fine as I only have limited items at the moment - but in my real app this is not a solution as I may have hundreds of items in my list

Comment: I have added an issue here -> https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/43605

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug seems to have been resolved in V1.9.1 hotfix

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/commit/68587a0916366e9512a78df22c44163d041dd5f3